Nuestra asociación con OpenAI (traducción)
Entrada Original: Our Partnership with OpenAI

Hoy anunciamos una nueva e interesante asociación con OpenAI. Nos complace que OpenAI comparta nuestro compromiso con una IA socialmente responsable.
Puedes encontrar más detalles en el comunicado de prensa.
Compartimos actualizaciones sobre asociaciones aquí en Meta porque creemos en brindarte un espacio para puedas hacer preguntas sobre ellas. Las asociaciones son otra fuente de ingresos para nosotros, similar a Stack Overflow for Teams o Publicidad, que nos permite financiar iniciativas en beneficio de la comunidad.
A medida que comience el trabajo en el futuro, tendremos más que compartir sobre cómo funcionarán las integraciones con nuestros socios.
En términos de fases del proyecto, estamos en el comienzo. Hay mucho trabajo de análisis y codificación por hacer, y durante ese tiempo, cualquier promesa específica sobre el funcionamiento podría cambiar. Queremos estar seguros de no engañar a las personas, sin darnos cuenta, en estos anuncios iniciales.

Más allá de toda esa palabrería tratando de justificar que se vendieron, no debe sorprender a nadie este movimiento. Stack Exchange està sedienta de dinero y OpenAI de datos ¿qué puede salir mal? Personalmenre creo que SO está muerto y hay gente que decidirá no trabajarle gratuitamente a estas empresas privadas que mueven millones mientras uno se duerme tarde escribiendo una respuesta que amanecerá con votos negativos. No se sorprendan si el mismo chatgpt empieza a preguntar en el sitio.

Por favor, no atacar al post traducido ni al traductor, vayan directo a la fuente.

Que buena noticia ...

Pregunto: Esto es positivo o negativo?, en que influye esto en la comunidad y en mi?

@aeportugal Que tiene de malo esa asociación? (1) Es normal que una empresa deba ganar dinero de lo que hace. Si la empresa no hace eso, va a la quiebra o no tiene motivaciones. (2) Supongo que lo harán por el camino legal, por lo que se explicitarán las medidas como se esperaría. Solo espero que no pongan una pequeña parte en los "terminos y condiciones" diciendo que venden nuestros datos. Voy a estar atento a cualquier mención de eso. (3) OpenAI ya estudió de prepo nuestras respuestas, así que ni idea que harán.

Lo unico malo que se me ocurre que podría pasar, es que terminen permitiendo respuestas con IA mezcladas con respuestas humanas, causando problemas a quien no desea recurrir a la IA. No se que suceda, solo el tiempo lo dirá. Si no, espero que alguien cree un nuevo sitio similar a SO.

@DanteS. no dije que tuviese algo malo y tampoco es una cuestión anti-ai. Sabemos que los sitios comunitarios necesitan pagar alojamiento, mantenedores, logística y demás. El tema es una cuestión ética, donde los beneficios solo los tienen unos pocos, y no es solo por el dinero, pero lo más probable es que OpenAI no le de un incentivo a nadie por usar un producto que el propio usuario está manteniendo. No sabemos cómo evolucionará esto, pero ojalá si haya una retribución a la comunidad. Lo del descuento o un plan "Socio-SO" no suena mal.

Pienso que no es una "mala noticia" @FranciscoNuñezIALover solo que ojalá toda la comunidad salga beneficiada de esto, no solo los directivos. Y por el momento no han mencionado nada más.

por eso es una buena noticia ... para que la comunidad abra los ojos y se de cuenta quien es el que trabaja y quie es el que recibe veneficios ... hasta el sol de hoy ... de las ventas que ha tenido la compañia y las asociaciones... que prometian un mejor ambiente para los usuarios finales ... no he visto nada ...
